# Correct type of ssd

Tags: ssd, amd-ryzen

I want to upgrade my laptop to SSD storage. I am a little bit confused about choosing the correct type and interface of SSD. Please assist me.

Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 2500U
Laptop: ASUS X505-ZA

[image: SSD Slot]

Comment: What is specifically confusing you? A quick Google query gives me a perfectly straight answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a M.2 SSD M key, according to the image you posted.

When I check at the Asus product page, which at [this link](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-15-X505ZA/specifications/), your laptop has a M.2 SATA 3 SSD.

So, the one you need to purchase is M.2 SATA 3 SSD M key. You can easily find a lot of them from Amazon.